# How to call model methods in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to call the model method get_url() in the  tag in the template

models.py

```
class Department(Base):

  department_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

  def get_url(self):
      ct = ContentType.objects.get(model='department')
      url_name = ' %s:%s ' % (ct.app_label, ct.model)
      return reverse(url_name, args=(self.object_id))
```

template.html

```
    <a href="{% ? ... how to call the model method here.... ? %}"></a>
```

Comment: This is documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#variables : "If a variable resolves to a callable, the template system will call it with no arguments and use its result instead of the callable."

Answer (score 6):

Pass the model instance to template via context

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['instance'] = Department.objects.get(id=1)
    return context

<a href="{{ instance.get_url }}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

```
class Department(Base):

  department_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

  def get_url(self):
      ct = ContentType.objects.get(model='department')
      url_name = ' %s:%s ' % (ct.app_label, ct.model)
      return reverse(url_name, args=(self.pk))  # <-- Changed to self.pk to access primary key of the object
```

Then you can use it in template like this:

```
 <a href="{{ object.get_url }}"></a>
```

#### Update

For accessing the instance of model in template, you need to send it to Template through context. In a function based view, you can try like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def some_view(request):
   department = Department.objects.first()
   context = { 'object': department }  # Here you can use any key in dictionary, I am using object. This key is accessible in template
   return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

Comment: {{ object.get_url }} how to get this object

Comment: @beginners please see the update section of my answer. hope it helps.